# reading a com port

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to interface with a cdc card reader which outputs to a virtual com port.  How does one go about opening  a stream to read from a com port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SerialPort from System.IO.Ports.SerialPort

It is available as a Form component in the Toolbox under Toolbox->Components->SerialPort

In the properties, you can select which COM port you want to connect to

Since your question relates to a stream object I think you can use SerialPort.BaseStream and cast it into a StreamWriter/StreamReader